# Why WordPress won't update via VPN?

Tags: php

I have a local WordPress site, working well, but I cannot make it update via my proxy VPN, saying ""WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org"

I have no problem accessing internet via the VPN, so quick question, is it WordPress simply doesn't support connecting to wordpress.org over a VPN?

Comment: What VPN provider you use?

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. I have set proxy in wp-config.php, it didn't work, and displays ' could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org' with debug mode. I set my localproxy listen to public IP addresses, still the same error.
But when I use `curl www.wordpress.org` or `wget www.wordpress.org`, it just works fine.